# How to correctly syntax a chained promise function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list that I would like it to go through a function and make some fixes on that list, so I can use it later.

Because its function is depended on the result of the previous, I decided to use the chained defer, to wait one another.

```
    var $q = Promise;
  $scope.list = function(scan_result) {

  return $q.resolve(scan_result)
    .then(function(scan_result) {
      // Creates an object list with bssid and signal
      const ap_list = scan_result.map(str => {
        return {
          bssid: str.match(/BSSID:\s(\S*)/)[1],
          signal: str.match(/Signal:\s(\S*)/)[1]
        }
      });
      console.log("1st Then:");
      console.log(ap_list);
      return ap_list;
    })

  .then(function(ap_list) {
  //Sort the elements Highest to Lowest Signal Level
  ap_list.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.signal - a.signal;
  });
  console.log("2nd Then:");
  console.log(ap_list);
  return ap_list;
})

  .then(function(ap_list) {
    //Removes the elements that have signal bellow -50
    for (var i = 0; i < ap_list.length; i++) {
      if (ap_list[i].signal < -50) {
        ap_list.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log("3rd Then:");
    console.log(ap_list);
    return ap_list;
  })

  .then(function(ap_list) {
    //From the list keep the highest 3
    //console.log(ap_list);
    console.log("4th Then:");
    console.log(ap_list.slice(0, 3));
    return ap_list.slice(0, 3);
  })
}


$scope.checkin = function() {
  var scan_result = $scope.getList();
  console.log(scan_result);
  $scope.list(scan_result)
    .then(function(result) {
      //console.log(result);
    })
}
```

When I output the result of the $scope.list() function on the console, it says the promise is pending and the status equals to 0.

So, definitely something is wrong here. Im not a defer guru so I kindly ask for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a promise that is responsible for resolving itself...*after* it has been resolved. That's a contradiction, and that's why your promise never resolves. You're also trying to resolve a single promise multiple times, which is not possible. A promise can only be resolved once.

From your example code, I really don't see any reason to use promises, since it's not doing anything asynchronously, but if you really want to use them, the below example should work. You should stop using `defer`; it's outdated and there is almost always a better way.

```js
// setup mock objects for this example
var $scope = { getList: function () { return ["BSSID: b0:c5:54:dd:e1:20 Signal: -21", "BSSID: c0:05:c2:6d:b1:9f Signal: -34", "BSSID: c0:05:c2:6d:b1:99 Signal: -33", "BSSID: 70:50:af:1f:0b:51 Signal: -80", "BSSID: 76:ea:a8:53:5c:9f Signal: -89", "BSSID: 90:21:06:af:99:65 Signal: -56", "BSSID: d8:fe:e3:e8:51:a6 Signal: -80", "BSSID: 24:de:c6:fb:7c:90 Signal: -89", "BSSID: 6c:c2:17:21:8a:47 Signal: -89", "BSSID: 24:de:c6:fb:7c:91 Signal: -90"]; } };
var $q = Promise;

$scope.list = function(scan_result) {

  return $q.resolve(scan_result)
    .then(function(scan_result) {
      // Creates an object list with bssid and signal
      const ap_list = scan_result.map(str => {
        return {
          bssid: str.match(/BSSID:\s(\S*)/)[1],
          signal: str.match(/Signal:\s(\S*)/)[1]
        }
      });
      console.log(ap_list);
      return ap_list;
    })

  .then(function (ap_list) {
    //Removes the elements that have signal bellow -50
    ap_list = ap_list.filter(el => el.signal >= -50);

    console.log(ap_list);
    return ap_list;
  })

  .then(function (ap_list) {
    //Sort the elements Highest to Lowest Signal Level
    ap_list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.signal - b.signal;
    });
    console.log(ap_list);
    return ap_list;
  })

  .then(function(ap_list) {
    //From the list keep the highest 3
    ap_list = ap_list.slice(0, 3);
    console.log(ap_list);
    return ap_list;
  })
}

$scope.checkin = function() {
  var scan_result = $scope.getList();
  $scope.list(scan_result)
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    })
}

$scope.checkin();
```

Comment: Hi JLRishe, thanks for your answer, I have updated my code with yours. Im getting the result I need, the way I need but Im still getting wrong results. For example: Our scan result have an index of 10 but the first then lists only 6. On the 3rd  .then the result should be an array of index 3 since we have only -21, -34 and -33 above the -50 limit. Check [link](http://prnt.sc/erk5y8)

Comment: @user3047017 Please provide a copy/paste-able copy of your input data.

Comment: ["BSSID: b0:c5:54:dd:e1:20 Signal: -21", "BSSID: c0:05:c2:6d:b1:9f Signal: -34", "BSSID: c0:05:c2:6d:b1:99 Signal: -33", "BSSID: 70:50:af:1f:0b:51 Signal: -80", "BSSID: 76:ea:a8:53:5c:9f Signal: -89", "BSSID: 90:21:06:af:99:65 Signal: -56", "BSSID: d8:fe:e3:e8:51:a6 Signal: -80", "BSSID: 24:de:c6:fb:7c:90 Signal: -89", "BSSID: 6c:c2:17:21:8a:47 Signal: -89", "BSSID: 24:de:c6:fb:7c:91 Signal: -90"]

Comment: @user3047017 Thank you. I see no way that you could have only 6 elements the first time `ap_list` is written to the console. If you run my snippet, you will see that it outputs 10 items. Your approach for removing certain items, using a `for` loop and `.splice` was clumsy and had a major bug. I've replaced it with `.filter` and that works. Also, your use of `.slice` had an off-by-one error. If you want up to 3 items, you should use `.slice(0, 3)` not `.slice(0, 2)`. I've fixed that above as well.

Comment: I wish I could give you more kudos. Thank you for your time and effort JLRishe! Your answer will be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> it says the promise is pending and the status equals to 0.

Promise must need to either `resolve or reject` to complete its state.

You not doing it,So,it is in `pending state.`

To chain the promise,you must return the [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
$scope.list = function(scan_result) {

  var defer = $q.defer();


  defer.promise
    .then(function() {
       //code
      defer.resolve(ap_list);
      return defer.promise;
    })

  .then(function(ap_list) {
    //code
    defer.resolve(ap_list);
    return defer.promise;

  })

  .then(function(ap_list) {
    //code

    defer.resolve(ap_list);
    return defer.promise;
  })

  .then(function(ap_list) {
    //From the list keep the highest 3
    defer.resolve(ap_list.slice(0, 2));
    return defer.promise;
  })


  defer.resolve() //EDIT CODE

  return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still something is not right. Have look on the link bellow [link](http://prnt.sc/erj1us)

Comment: What you expect?

Comment: The result I need to get is the new list with the modifications done. I know it will be in an promise object, but I cant find the new list in that object.

Comment: then in your promise success use that one in your business login and return the modified one

Comment: Thanks for your time Ritchie. I have updated my code with your suggestions. And I also included console.log in each .then. But they never been called. So for an unknown reason the functions I guess are not called at all.

Comment: @user3047017 can u please console `scan_result` or `app_list`

Comment: I have update the 1st question with the exact code I am using. I have also made some changes in my checkin function that I use to call the list function. I tried to console ap_list but none of the was executed. I appreciate your effort Ritchie.

Comment: @user3047017 my bad.We need to start the promise chain `first.defer.resolve() //EDIT CODE` add this one and try it again

Comment: You mean on the first .then function instead of using defer. resolve(ap_list) to use first.defer.resolve(ap_list) ?

Comment: check my EDIT.We need to inite the promise with resolve state

Comment: Thanks Ritchie. I think JLRishe's is in a "working" state, but the results are not accurate enough. You can start from there if you still want to involved into finding a solution. Have a look on the 1st question again and on the JLRishe's answers comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.list` function returns promise, so you have to wait result from it.

```
$scope.list()
   .then(function(result) {     
      console.log(result);
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not return `defer.promise`, but the result of the chained `then` calls, so put `return` here :

```
return defer.promise
     .then(function(){
         // etc...
```

...and then you need to keep using the `then` method also when you treat the return value of your function:

```
$scope.list().then(ap_list => console.log(ap_list));
```